# Unable to add rules to /etc/ufw/before.rules and before6.rules

Tags: 20.04, iptables, firewall, ufw, ntp

I run a high-traffic NTP server and the following rules are absolutely necessary to prevent my conntrack table from being immediately overrun (regardless of how large it is):

```
iptables -t raw -A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 123 -j NOTRACK
iptables -t raw -A OUTPUT -p udp --sport 123 -j NOTRACK
ip6tables -t raw -A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 123 -j NOTRACK
ip6tables -t raw -A OUTPUT -p udp --sport 123 -j NOTRACK
```

I'm searching for the best way to have these rules applied automatically at bootup. They need to be applied immediately when UFW goes up or the conntrack table will be full in seconds. (Please don't suggest increasing the size of the conntrack table; I don't want to waste resources tracking these connections at all and the table would have to be absurdly large in order to do so, probably more than the server could handle.)

I first tried adding them to /etc/ufw/before.rules and before6.rules like this, at the end of the files:

```
# tail before.rules before6.rules
==> before.rules <==
(stuff that was already there)

-t raw -A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 123 -j NOTRACK
-t raw -A OUTPUT -p udp --sport 123 -j NOTRACK

# don't delete the 'COMMIT' line or these rules won't be processed
COMMIT

==> before6.rules <==
(stuff that was already there)

-t raw -A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 123 -j NOTRACK
-t raw -A OUTPUT -p udp --sport 123 -j NOTRACK

# don't delete the 'COMMIT' line or these rules won't be processed
COMMIT
```

However upon reboot the system had no network connectivity and I observed the following error:

```
ERROR: problem running ufw-init                                                                              
iptables-restore v1.8.4 (legacy): The -t option (seen in line 75) cannot be used in iptables-restore.        
                                                                                                             
Error occurred at line: 75                                                                                   
Try `iptables-restore -h' or 'iptables-restore --help' for more information.                                 
ip6tables-restore v1.8.4 (legacy): The -t option (seen in line 142) cannot be used in ip6tables-restore.     
                                                                                                             
Error occurred at line: 142                                                                                  
Try `ip6tables-restore -h' or 'ip6tables-restore --help' for more information.                               
                                                                                                             
Problem running '/etc/ufw/before.rules'                                                                      
Problem running '/etc/ufw/before6.rules'
```

I next tried removing the "-t raw":

```
# tail before.rules before6.rules
==> before.rules <==
(stuff that was already there)

-A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 123 -j NOTRACK
-A OUTPUT -p udp --sport 123 -j NOTRACK

# don't delete the 'COMMIT' line or these rules won't be processed
COMMIT

==> before6.rules <==
(stuff that was already there)

-A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 123 -j NOTRACK
-A OUTPUT -p udp --sport 123 -j NOTRACK

# don't delete the 'COMMIT' line or these rules won't be processed
COMMIT
```

This once again killed network connectivity and threw an error:

```
ERROR: problem running ufw-init
iptables-restore: line 75 failed
ip6tables-restore: line 142 failed

Problem running '/etc/ufw/before.rules'
Problem running '/etc/ufw/before6.rules'
```

What is the best way to handle this?

Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

EDIT:  after playing around with "iptables-save" a bit I tried adding things like this to the file:

```
*raw
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -p udp -m udp --dport 123 -j NOTRACK
-A OUTPUT -p udp -m udp --sport 123 -j NOTRACK
```

However I always get the same errors:

```
# ufw enable
Command may disrupt existing ssh connections. Proceed with operation (y|n)? y
ERROR: problem running ufw-init
Bad argument `*raw'
Error occurred at line: 75
Try `iptables-restore -h' or 'iptables-restore --help' for more information.

Problem running '/etc/ufw/before.rules'
```

and my server's network connectivity is killed until I either disable UFW or remove the added lines from the files and reload UFW.

Answer (score 1):

My first mistake was trying to add "raw" rules into the existing block, which is defined as a "filter" block.  I needed to add a whole new "raw" block with its own COMMIT, like this:

```
*raw
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -p udp -m udp --dport 123 -j NOTRACK
-A OUTPUT -p udp -m udp --sport 123 -j NOTRACK
COMMIT
```

I attempted to add it at the end of the file (after the existing "COMMIT") but for some reason it still errored out, but it worked when I added to the start of the file. Not sure why.

So the overall structure of before.rules and before6.rules now look like this:

```
*raw
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
(my rules here)
COMMIT

*filter
:ufw6-before-input - [0:0]
:ufw6-before-output - [0:0]
:ufw6-before-forward - [0:0]
(existing rules here)
COMMIT
```